# htaccess redirect for virtuemart

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've setup a virtuemart ecommerce.
All ok with htaccess and redirect, store is in

```
http://www.domainname.com/it/store/
```

But the "only" problem is it that both url are valid:

```
http://www.domainname.com/it/store/article.html
```

and (note absence of "store")

```
http://www.domainname.com/it/article.html
```

creating problem with google and overall that in this mode article.html inherit settings of home page (banners, etc).

So, i would to redirect via htaccess any request sent to an URL without store to URL with /store.

.htaccess is default of Joomla:

```
##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/store/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1/store/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: With your code site seems doesn't recall correctly css, jquery, etc :(

Comment: Update: css, jquery etc doesn't function because Joomla engine now search them in "www.domain.com/store/templates". Of course "store" doesn't exist...

Comment: Update: css, jquery etc doesn't function because Joomla engine now search them in "www.domain.com/store/templates". Of course "store" doesn't exist...

Comment: We are on the right road! now, all seems to work, but not home page... Home page need to be "only" http//www.domain.com/it (without store), otherwise i have blank page... Thank you very much!